# Material-web-component scss build

Tags: webpack, web-component

I'm fairly new to webpack, but I'm not sure if this is a configuration problem or not. My build fails because of an error in my scss, or (material-web-compenents itself). When I try to build webpack throws this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/styles.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
                                             ^
      Argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color
```

My config file:

```
/*
    ./webpack.config.js
*/
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }]
  }
}
```

It will build if I remove all my variables. The stack trace shows it originating from the mdc components.
SCSS file:

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #37474F !default;
$mdc-theme-primary-light: mdc-theme-light-variant($mdc-theme-primary) !default;
$mdc-theme-primary-dark: mdc-theme-dark-variant($mdc-theme-primary) !default;
$mdc-theme-secondary: #B0BEC5 !default;

@import "~@material/theme/mdc-theme";
```

Comment: Can we see your Sass file that contains this code?

Comment: I added the scss code. The rest of the file isn't using the variables or anything, so I left that out.